Weighted Bessel potential space is a Banach space?
I'm studying weighted $L^p$ spaces. In
O. Christensen, Functions, Spaces, and Expansions: Mathematical Tools in Physics and Engineering (Birkhäuser, Boston, Mass, 2010), weighted $L^p$ space is presented (in an exercise) as
\begin{align}
L_w^p(\mathbb{R})=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\colon \left\|f\right\|_{L_{w}^p(\mathbb{R})}=\left\|wf\right\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})}<\infty\right\}
\end{align}
where $w:\mathbb{R}\to ]0,\infty[$ is a weight (a continuous function). This space, $L_w^p(\mathbb{R})$, is a Banach space.
Now, in M. Cwikel, and M. Milman, editors , Functional Analysis, Harmonic Analysis, and Image Processing (American Mathematical                     Society, Providence, Rhode Island, 2017), the Bessel potential spaces is defined:
Let $w$ a function on $\mathbb{R}$ non-negative, locally integrable which is not almost everywhere $0$. The weighted Bessel potential spaces is:
\begin{align}
L_{s}^{p}(w)=\left\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\colon \left\|f\right\|_{L_s^p(w)}=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\right\|_{L^p(w)}<\infty\right\}
\end{align}
Question. Is the weighted Bessel potential space a Banach space?

What have you tried? For example, is there no way to adapt the proof for the completeness of the usual Bessel potential spaces (unweighted) to your case?
